# pull search form to the right within a well

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get a search form to pull-right within a well. it pulls to the right but moves south of the well.

the code i have is;

```
<div class="container">
<div class="well">

    <div class="pull-right">
<form class="form-inline " role="form">
    <input type="search" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search Assets">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
</form>

</div>
```

I've done a jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/3366/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear float after your floated div.

**[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/52VtD/3369/)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="well">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <form class="form-inline " role="form">
                <input type="search" class="form-control" id="search" placeholder="Search Assets">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</div>
```